# Add multiple lines to detailTextLabel in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I'm using a `UITableView` with cell style of `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`.

I'm want to have multiple lines in the `detailTextLabel`, is that possible? Or do I have to make a custom cell?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set `cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2` to get 2 lines in there. However, I doubt UITableViewCell will lay out the labels as you expect in that case. You may want to subclass UITableViewCell and override `-layoutSubviews` to position the labels how you want. You can call `[super layoutSubviews]` and then just tweak the positions of the labels. You'll probably want to use `-[NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:]` to calculate the correct size for the detail text label.

Alternatively, instead of subclassing UITableViewCell, you could try doing the tweaks in `-tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:`, though if the cell ever decides it needs to re-layout, then your tweaks will be erased. I recommend you go with the subclassing approach.

*Edit*: BTW, with the subclass approach, all you have to do is change `[UITableViewCell alloc]` to `[MyTableViewCellSubclass alloc]`. Since you're not introducing new methods or properties, the variable can still remain typed as a UITableViewCell and you won't have to change any other code.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I subclassed UITableViewCell but I created a nib to layout the labels instead of doing it programmatically. Would that be any different than what you are suggesting me doing. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Creating a nib is perfectly fine (though if you're on iOS 4.0 I recommend using `UINib` to optimize the nib loading). The benefit to tweaking the labels using `-layoutSubviews` is you can reuse the existing `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel` properties, but you are by no means required to use those.

Comment: `cell.detailTextLabel` in recent swift versions is now an optional so `cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2` should be `cell.detailTextLabel!.numberOfLines = 2`

Comment: No it should be `cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 2`. Force-unwraping means your whole app will crash if you run that line on a cell that doesn't have a detail label.

Answer (score 3):

The detailTextLabel is a UILabel, the word wrapping rules apply just like with a label you create.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/lineBreakMode

EDIT: Just thought, you'll also need to change the height of the cell if the text gets beyond some threshold of lines. probably 2 or 3 is okay.

Answer (score 2):

At least on iOS 11 it works great just adding this line.

```
cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

On SWIFT 4.0 and above:

```
cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
```

Unless you never want to have more than 2 lines, do not set numberOfLines to 2 as advices in the comments because it's not an efficient way to code. It's not dynamic. The number of lines might be different base on your screen size, accessibility settings etc. Setting numberOfLines to 0, let the OS use as many lines necessary to display properly your text.