# Why is the cell not resizing with its content?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, resize

I have read all of the similar questions I could find here and applied all of the proposed solutions ... none of them works.

The table view is a grouped-one, the number of lines for the `textLabel` and the `detailTextLabel` is set to 0 both in code and in the storyboard, the string data is made of a multiline string created via `"\n"` characters...

Setting `tableView.estimatedRowHeight` to something else rather than the automatic 43.5 and then `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` as suggested in some other questions does absolutely nothing... or if I put something like 100, it will resize all the cells instead of just the ones which have multiple lines of text.

I am unfamiliar with this type of behaviour from table views: in my experience, simply putting the number of lines to 0 for the labels just worked...

Why do I get this result?

[image: shrank image]

EDIT: I have also tried to implement the `heightForRowAt` method, passing in the desired sections and rows but nothing at all changed ... I am lost.

EDIT (2): Removed previous snippet and inserted ViewController source code: the only thing I can show that is relevant to the cell is this, as the only property is an instance of a custom data type that is populating the table view (and it is being very good at that) and `viewDidLoad()` has nothing of mine added inside of it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        cell.detailTextLabel?.numberOfLines = 0

        func configureTextLabels(withString labelText: String, and detailText: String) {
            cell.textLabel?.text = labelText
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = detailText
        }

        if let country = detailCountry {
            switch indexPath.section {
            // insert 14 different cases here
            case 14: 
                func populateRows() {
                    let regionalBlocs = country.regionalBlocs

                    for i in 0 ..< regionalBlocs.count {
                        switch indexPath.row {
                        case 0 + (i * 4): configureTextLabels(withString: "Name: ", and: "\(regionalBlocs[i].name)")
                        case 1 + (i * 4): configureTextLabels(withString: "\tAcronym: ", and: "\(regionalBlocs[i].acronym)")
                        case 2 + (i * 4):
                            var detailText = ""
                            let otherNames = regionalBlocs[i].otherNames

                            if !otherNames.isEmpty {
                                for name in otherNames {
                                    if name == otherNames.last {
                                        detailText += name
                                    } else {
                                        detailText += "\(name)\n"
                                    }
                                }
                                configureTextLabels(withString: "\tOther names: ", and: detailText)
                            } else {
                                configureTextLabels(withString: "", and: "No other names found")
                            }
                        case 3 + (i * 4):
                            var detailText = ""
                            let otherAcronyms = regionalBlocs[0].otherAcronyms

                            if !otherAcronyms.isEmpty {
                                for acronym in otherAcronyms {
                                    if acronym == otherAcronyms.last {
                                        detailText += acronym
                                    } else {
                                        detailText += "\(acronym)\n"
                                    }
                                }
                                configureTextLabels(withString: "\tOther acronyms: ", and: detailText)
                            } else {
                                configureTextLabels(withString: "", and: "No other acronym found")
                            }
                        default: break
                        }
                    }
                }

                let regionalBlocs = country.regionalBlocs

                if regionalBlocs.isEmpty {
                    cell.textLabel?.text = ""
                    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "No regional bloc data found for this country"
                } else {
                    populateRows()
                }
            }
        return cell
        }
```

Comment: Please show the constrant of that cell

Comment: I have set no constraint as I am using the default Table View Controller in the storyboard and then set everything else in code. Shouldn't the cell's label autoresize when the text is on multiple lines?

Comment: Are you have hardfix heightForRow function return value

Comment: Can you upload the sample project?

Comment: No hardfix, `heightForRow`
 is not overridden. I am very puzzled by these results ... The project is very big and the sample code is what concerns this section of the table view ... the rest is just other data. Basically a huge `cellForRowAt`

Comment: Please provide viewController source code

Comment: Done ... this is all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look answer in here: [Add multiple lines to detailTextLabel in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3535456/add-multiple-lines-to-detailtextlabel-in-uitableviewcell)

But I suggest you create custom cell for this case, your issue is UIKit's bug.

Comment: Thanks but the suggestion there is to set the number of lines to 0, which I have done... how would I go about creating a custom cell? Just create a `UITableViewCell` subclass with nothing new inside and simply adopt it as the class of the cell inside IB?

Comment: Learn more about create custom cell: https://medium.com/q-software/ios-custom-table-views-with-cells-2e4ba692cfc8

Comment: ...anyway ... I created one, changed the class inheritance in IB ... nothing ... still same issue ...

Comment: @NotationMaster no no, not just only change class inheritance. You need create cell and you need constraint labels by your self.

Comment: @NotationMaster You can try my demo: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1knIqdcrSu9ldLM_yEcjQJUIwQmJUlKlg

Comment: Hey @Thank Vu! It is starting to work now, just suddenly the lines do not wrap anymore as before ... Why? I now have a string that instead of dividing into two lines it disappears beyond the edge of the screen.

Comment: I don't understand. please provide picture

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7bqjc2x7xg6yx6m/Screenshot%202019-09-03%20at%2004.28.00.png?dl=0

Comment: @NotationMaster It maybe not relate with current issue.

Comment: Sorry, my bad ... I had forgotten a constraint! Thanks! I will mark your suggestion as solving answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198853/discussion-between-notationmaster-and-thanh-vu).